# Bash 4.3 yum repository for Amazon Linux

Tags: bash, yum, ec2, aws

I'm trying to get bash 4.2 (or a more recent version) on Amazon Linux in ec2. The default repository only has Bash 4.1. I'm looking for a `yum` repository with a recent version.

```
$ sudo yum install bash
...
Package bash-4.1.2-15.23.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

This question has now been [cross posted to serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/650370/how-best-to-maintain-a-recent-bash-version-on-amazon-linux) where they have an [amazon-linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-linux) tag. Probably should have posted there first.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo yum update bash`?

Comment: @ryekayo Yes I have.

Comment: Can you try this: `sudo yum update-to bash-4.3*`?

Comment: @ryekayo `No package bash-4.3* available.`

Comment: Ok try this: `yum list available bash`. This will list all available versions for bash for amazon linux. Something tells me that they only support bash 4.1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any repositories that will provide you with BASH 4.3 for Amazon Linux.

If you have a specific requirement for this version of BASH then you're probably going to have to compile it from source, if you've no experience in doing that then this could be quite technical, there are some instructions on this over at the BASH FAQ; ftp://ftp.cwru.edu/pub/bash/FAQ.

Is there a specific reason that you need BASH 4.3? I'd be interested to hear it if so.

UPDATE: I've just spun up an Amazon EC2 instance running the latest version of Amazon Linux and upgraded bash by compiling from source. There was no dependency issues and everything worked as expected for me.

Download the latest package from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3.tar.gz and follow the install instructions from http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter06/bash.html. Once done I rebooted the system and it booted fine using the new version of bash. I tried running a couple of scripts I had laying around which worked with older versions of BASH and they appear fine.

Obviously if this is a production system please test on a dev/staging/test environment first!

Comment: I don't necessarily need 4.3 actually, but I do need 4.2 to support scripts that use `[[ -v VARIABLE ]]`. I will edit the question to specify that.

Comment: @TravisWellman I've just updated my answer, I tested compiling from source and all appeared to work quite well.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It isn't really the answer I need, so I can't really accept it. I would upvote your answer for being useful, but I don't have 15 rep yet.

Comment: No problem, sorry I couldn't be of more help :)